# node.js session values aren't accessible in second api call

Tags: node.js, session

i am facing the following issue:
(I am using [node-client-sessions](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions) module)

I send an ajax request, **through the browser**, to my API : `/api/request1`
In my api.js I handle that request, calculate some stuff and write some results into the session like this.

```
router.post('/request1', function(req, response, next) {
// some wield calculations
req.session.calcData = { // some content }; 
// some other calculations
console.log(req.session.calcData); // logs the correct object
response.send('success');
}
```

After receiving the success on client side I send another api call like this for example: `/api/request2`

```
router.post('/request2', function(req, response, next) {
  // here i want to use some of the results from the previous calculations which i stored in the calcData session.
 console.log(req.session.calcData); // this logs undefined
}
```

Shouldn't req.session.calcData be available in both functions?

**Enviroment Info**

Express Framework 4.x

app.js :

```
...
var app = express();
...
var session = require('client-sessions');
...
app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: 'random_string_goes_here',
  duration: 30 * 60 * 9999999,
  activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
}));
...
app.use('/api', api);
```

Comment: How do you initialize the session module ? How to you call `/api/requestX` (curl, browser, ...) ?

Comment: I have updated my Question with extra information.

Answer (score 1):

According to example at [client-session](https://github.com/DoubleSpout/nodeClientSession#express-4x-example), you must use `req.csession` and `req.csflush();`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path')
var cs = require('client-session');
var clientSession = cs('mysecretkey');
var app = express();
app.use(clientSession.connect());
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var count = req.csession['count'];
  if(!count) count = 1;
  else count++;
  req.csession['count'] = count;
  //sync to cookie session equal to res.csflush(),make sure to call it before response
  req.csflush(); 
  res.send(count.toString());
});
app.listen(8124);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

Comment: Notice: It seems he mixes the usage of [`session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session) with the module [`client-session`](https://github.com/DoubleSpout/nodeClientSession). Maybe you can add a line to clarify that.

Comment: @Cyrbil How do you mean that?

Comment: I seem to be using a different module "client-sessions" with an s at the end https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions

Comment: `request.session.xxx` is part of express's session module. Meanwhile you are importing `client-sessions` that is another module.

Comment: according to https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions the usade of this module is req.sessionName - I am confused now

Comment: @AlexeyB. I have updated my question in the meantime with the link to the module I use and some other additional information - do you happen to know a solution for that too ? :)